# I need to know to create a new efi partition for windows 10 from the recovery terminal

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning

I have had my efi boot partition deleted while deleting linux and I need to get it back ASAP, please help. I have access to the recovery console or if need be I can install a third party tool and boot to it and use it.

Answer (score -1):

I am quoting myself from another post. You may skip to step 5, but if you have problems follow all of them. I added step 11 just in case there is an issue.

1. Download the Windows 10 ISO by using using the Media Creation Tool from their [site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) with another computer.
2. Either burn it to a disk find directions online or as I recommend put it on a flash drive with more than 3.5 GB (at the moment, minimum depends on ISO file's size). Use the tool called [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) to put it on the flash drive. Now you may have to try and repeat till this boots correctly in the next step. Try UEFI and GPT; If that doesn't boot try BIOS and MBR, then UEFI and MBR. You select these in the rufus drop down menu.
3. Boot up to it. If it is UEFI, often times you can press Esc to give you a menu. Else you may have to try out some F1-F12 keys. Or choose what it says if it shows the keys to press. You can also go to bios and change the boot order to the device you are using.
4. At a successful load into the Installation, you first want to go to "Repair your computer." You will be lead to a screen with multiple buttons. Try these in sequential order to help you (I tried ordering them from easiest to hardest)
5. Navigate to something "Fix Startup." Try it, if fails, move on, if succeed, restart computer. (If you only have access to command prompt this will not work, proceed).
6. Navigate to Command Prompt.
7. Run the command `bootrec /scanos`. If it says it found 1, there is an OS, skip to 9. If it is 0, don't get your hopes down, because this often lies (to me atleast).
8. Run the command `diskpart`. In Diskpart then run `list volume`. If it says something that is identifiable to your OS you are in luck ("NTFS...", "Boot", "System", About the same partition size, etc...) and you should continue trying to fix it. Note the assigned drive letter it was given. If not assigned a drive letter (e.g. "C") run `sel vol <``number of what it is>`. Then assign the letter with `assign letter=c` (replace the letter c with whatever). If not I am sorry, If you need your files you should do some research on how to recover it, if it is still there. Then type `exit`
9. Run this command `bootrec /fixboot`. If you had 1 or more OSs show up when we scanned then run `bootrec /rebuildbcd`. If success, restart. If not, next step.
10. Assign a drive letter to the volume if not already, as we did in step 8. Run this `dir c:` (replace letter). If it lists "Windows" in the directory, you may be able to continue recovery. If not you have to reinstall it. If you want to recover your potentially lost files, you are going to have do research on your own. If it does list it, run `bcdedit c:\windows` (replace letter). If it works, restart your computer. If not, Sorry.
11. I would try this if all else fails, just in case bcd store is corrupted or something else (if it still there). We want to make it unallocated space. In diskpart (look at step 8), run `list disk`. Find the disk in which the EFI boot partition was stored on, remember the value. Run `sel disk <number of what it is>.` Run `list part` Find that partition if it is there of where the EFI partition was, remember the value. Run `sel part <number of what it is>.` Then finally run `delete partition`. Try all the steps again 5-10.

Good Luck!

Comment: Hi I just want to leave a note saying that `bootrec /fixboot` is extremely dangerous and please don't just run it. It nuked my ventoy exFAT partition