# Installed Windows on new SSD but bootloader did not get installed on new SSD

Tags: windows-10, boot, windows-11, bootloader

I'm looking for the standard workaround/resolution for this scenario:

- Add new disk to computer
- Use installation media (win11 iso) to install new OS (Windows 11) on fresh partition spanning new disk
- While booting up, BIOS/UEFI is targeting original disk. Presents Windows boot menu (Choose between Win 11 and Win 10).
- Remove old disk
- No bootable OS detected by BIOS/UEFI

What are the next steps for each of the following possible paths forward?

1. Assuming old disk has been sold, want to install a bootloader on the new disk so already-installed new OS can be used. Would be most convenient at this point to do it via booting into Linux Live USB. Looking for tool suggestions. One example that I hope might work: Boot to Ubuntu LiveUSB, install grub to new disk. If this would allow new disk to boot to win11 now, then this would be great.
2. After reconnecting old disk, which restores ability to boot, want to install the bootloader onto new disk, so that old disk can be actually removed. Does windows come with a tool (edit: Not reinstalling! that's a last resort here haha) that can be used for this purpose once we boot back into windows? I was looking at EasyBCD but their official site doesn't even say that Windows 11 is supported... I feel like [rebuilding bcd](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-rebuild-the-bcd-in-windows-2624508) also would probably just still install to the original disk after I reconnect it, which is not what I want.

I have the original disk handy. But I'd like to also take the opportunity now to learn whether it would be possible to restore bootability if I already did happen to get rid of the drive.

Comment: “Does windows come with a tool that can be used for this purpose once we boot back into windows?” - While there is a built-in tool that exists, and the process is well documented, It’s easier to just reinstall Windows without the old disk connected to the system.

Comment: That's really not convenient if the third bullet point has resulted in setup and usage already. I agree though that often it's just easier to reinstall. But: Although the initial installation step off the ISO is very fast on a modern system (around 1 or 2 minutes) the later setup steps with updates and entering wizards takes a good 30 minutes, so it's not really a good answer...

Comment: [Does the new disk have an EFI partition?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/create-partition-efi). Provide us your BCD information

Comment: @Ramhound I will boot into a Linux liveUSB and check that now. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Ramhound From Linux I see `fdisk` reporting that it is a gpt disklabel type, with two partitions, a 16M "Microsoft reserved",  and a 3.6T "Microsoft basic data". So it is a GPT disk but has no EFI boot partition on it.

Comment: I will try [this](https://superuser.com/a/1237591/98199), which looks like a reasonable workflow, and report back. Can't believe it took me this long to think about trying the repair functionality that installer media provides.

Comment: It did NOT work. Also I feel like running `bootrec /fixboot` caused it to wipe or screw up my Ventoy USB drive, now it reports "No ISO files found"... Wow...

Comment: Who asked you to run *bootrec /fixboot*? Good thing it’s trivial to recreate your Ventoy drive.

Comment: Your going to need to rebuild the BCD but only after the EFI exists to allow you to boot into Windows, but I won’t be able to help you.

Comment: Well the link i linked said to do that. That'll be the last time I do that. Ventoy now restored. I'm doing a fresh Win11 install now. Not worth the headache of trying to fix. It looks like the age old guidance is as true as ever: Installing windows? Disconnect or disable at BIOS/UEFI level all other drives on the machine. I'm realizing that that latter option is a neat life pro tip for not having to physically remove those NVMe drives that are stuck underneath thermal pads!

Comment: You found that link on your own, nobody here, said the instructions were correct. Just saying…